# How to add and update data into foreign key field in django model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have two models which is related to a forignkey.

```
class BikeModel(models.Model):
    City = models.ForeignKey(CityForBike, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    BikeModels = models.CharField(default='', max_length=50)
    Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='bike_images', blank=True, null=True, default='https://www.urbandrive.co.in/Admin/API/UploadedFiles/CarImage/44b150b3-f61a-41b5-afd8-34ded18fa980.png')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'BikeModels'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.BikeModels

class CityForBike(models.Model):
    CityForCars = models.CharField(default="",max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'CityForBikes'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.CityForCars
```

and i want to insert data to BikeModel. but it gives me error.

```
 AssertionError: You cannot call `.save()` on a serializer with invalid data.
```

I want to know how to insert data to forign key field.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    import pdb;
    pdb.set_trace()
    input_data = json.loads(request.read().decode('utf-8'))
    print(input_data)
    serializer = serializers.BikeModelSerializer(data=input_data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return render(request, "bike_model_add.html", {'car_city': car_city}, status=200)
```

And this is the data i am sending.

```
{'City': 'testo', 'BikeModels': 'ds'}
```

this is my serializers

```
class CityForBikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.CityForBike
        fields = '__all__'

class BikeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.BikeModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: You need to show BikeModelSerializer.

Comment: above are my BikeModelSerializer.

Comment: This is tagged as django, but `ModelSerializer` is not a django class: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/search/?q=ModelSerializer This look like django-rest-framework. Also, json should be like `{'City': 3, 'BikeModels': 'ds'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to identify cities by their name in the bike serializer, you need to use [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield).

```
class BikeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    City = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='CityForCars')

    class Meta:
        model = models.BikeModel
        fields = '__all__'
```